# write some bytes to a file and it will be downloaded to the local machine

Tags: asp.net

I have a question how to implement this in asp.net:

I have an asp.net webpage: if the user click on a hyperlink, for example: check.aspx. in the page check.aspx: I would like to write some bytes to a file with a specific name: 'test.abc'. writing is not to write on that file on the server. a temporary file or something like that.  then that file will be automatically downloaded the local machines.

For example: in the method: `page_Load()` of the webpage: check.aspx: it will response to the file test.abc and it will trigger the browser to download it.

How would this be achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MemoryStream` (System.IO) to write some bytes and later your may write it (bytes stream) to `Respose`'s output stream.

Comment: that does help. thanks! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.80).aspx